# Не работает отправка формы на jquery

Tags: jquery

Пытаюсь проверить поле *"email"* и отправить форму, если *"email"* не пусто и валидно. Но почему-то форма не отправляется.

```
var validEmail = 0;

    $("input[name='email']").blur(function() {
        if($(this).val() != '') {
            var pattern = /^([a-z0-9_\.-])+@[a-z0-9-]+\.([a-z]{2,4}\.)?[a-z]{2,4}$/i;
            if(pattern.test($(this).val())){
                validEmail = 1;
                $(this).removeClass("error");
            } else {
                validEmail = 0;
                $(this).addClass("error");
            }
        } else {
            validEmail = 0;
            $(this).addClass("error");
        }
    });



    $("input[type='submit']").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (validEmail == 1) {
            $(this).parents(".order_form").submit();
        }
        else {
            $(this).parents(".order_form").find("input[name='email']").addClass("error");
            $(this).parents(".order_form").find("input[name='email']").focus(); 
        }
    });
```

Форма найдена правильно, так как если вместо *submit()* написать *hide()*, то она скрывается.

Comment: А что будет, если  `e.preventDefault();` поместить в `else`?

Comment: Тогда форма отправится :-) Получается, что отмена стандартного действия навсегда происходит?

Comment: Думаю, это может зависеть от браузера.